# Can I prevent PdfLatex in WinEdt 10.0 from immediately displaying the pdf?

Tags: winedt

I am working on a large document with many graphics, so PdfLatex in WinEdt is a bit slow, and when the pdf opens it is hard for me to find my work point.  So each time I run PdfLatex I have to go back to the source file and use the very handy pointer in the left margin that takes me exactly to my work point in the pdf.

It would speed things up a lot if I could just keep the source file window up while PdfLatex runs, and not get the pdf displayed, until I hit the pointer that takes me to the right place in the pdf.

Is there an easy way to set that up?

Comment: this doesn't address the interaction of winedt with the pdf, but there might be some tactics that could help, depending on the nature of your document and how you need to look at the output.   if it is a book, you could prepare the chapters in separate files, and access them one at a time with `\include` and `\includeonly`.  if you really don't need to look at the graphics every time, you could compile with `[draft]` mode.  sorry i can't help with the winedt specifics.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, but these are lecture slides that need a lot of graphics, and I need to see how they look each time.

Comment: good reason.  next time you ask a question, you should include details like this -- it will keep people from speculating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're not using simply "PDFLaTeX" to compile your file, but WinEdt command "PDFTeXify", which by default compiles your bibliographies, glossaries, indexes, etc., and at the end of the compilation starts your PDF viewer.

The first thing I suggest is to use just "PDFLaTeX" to compile your file unless you want a "complete" complilation, so to speed up the whole process.

Simply select it from the compiler dropdown button in the toolbar.

[image]

Anyway, you can control all of these tools going to Options -> Execution Modes.

If "Start Viewer" is selected, then the viewer is launched at the end of the compilation. If also "Forward Search" is selected, then it is started with forward search enabled.

[image]

Comment: Yes! You are right I'm using PDFTeXify.  And since this is a pretty plain Beamer document (aside from xypic and included graphics) I may not need anything beyond actual PDFLaTeX.  I'll check.

Comment: Indeed using "Start Viewer" with "Forward Search" takes me directly from the source file to my work point in the PDF in one click.